Keyboard toolbar covering `TextField`
I'm trying to get the keyboard to respect the TextField when it's brought up. I understand that in iOS 14.2+, this is the default behavior. However, in my testing, I noticed that the keyboard's toolbar is still not taken into account. i.e. if the keyboard has an input accessory, it can still cover up the TextField. See the screenshot I attached.
Here's the code I used for testing:
struct CommentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "dog.jpeg")!)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 350, height: 500)
                .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        TextField("Add a comment", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .keyboardType(.default)
                            .submitLabel(.done)
                            .padding([.top, .bottom], 8)
                            .padding([.horizontal], 16)
                            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                                                            
                    }
                }
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
        }
    }
}

Toolbar covering the TextField:

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I cannot reproduce this on iOS 17.4. What version are you running?

Hmm interesting, I’m on iOS 18.0 (22A5326f), the latest beta. Maybe a bug?
